# Will SQL find like text values if the binaries are different?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to compare / find like email address from two tables. I used bad email logs in my SMTP server. The actual email addresses where extracted from the rest of the crud using a utility page I found online. These were pasted into Notepad and then imported into my SQL server `BadEmail2` table using SSMS import wizard.

When using a  query with `INNER JOIN` no records are returned. (Query below)

When using a SELECT query by copying and pasting an email address from the `BadEmail2` table into the WHERE of the query the correct record is returned.

By using CAST to `Varbinary` I found that the binary values for the same email addresses in both tables are entirely different in all cases.

Does this matter... is it the reason my `INNER JOIN` queries do not return any records? And if so, how do I do this right?

The query below returns no records-- although a simple SELECT query with Email address pasted from `BadEmails2` does work.

```sql
SELECT EmailAddress from Customers INNER JOIN BadEmails2
ON customers.EmailAddress = BadEmails2.BadEmailAdr
```

Qry1
[image: Qry1]

Qry2
[image]

Comment: `By using CAST to Varbinary I found that the binary values for the same email addresses in both tables are entirely different` - please show an example of that.

Comment: GSerg I have posted screenshots of two querie and http://216.117.4.16/Qrys.htm. I learned something very curious in the process. You will notice that the email address in the qry of customers table van also be found in the qry of the BadEmails2 at record 11. However if I cut and paste that address into the WHERE clause of a simple 1 table SELECT query no record is returned. That is, a query for all records works fine but a query for a value we know is in the table does not.

Comment: Your problem is that all the varchar email addresses have a leading line feed character `0x0a`

Comment: Those look suspiciously like real email addresses. You should not be posting production customer data to the web when asking questions

Comment: Thanks Martin, They are long proven bad email addresses but yes, you are right in any case. Thanks for your answer too... importing the data correctly fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem people! Turns out I probably made a mistake while importing the bad email addresses from the `.txt` file. Did not use "Flat File" as the source.

Thanks to all for leading me in the right direction- I learned a lot.

Answer (score -2):

Try COLLATE database_default on both sides of the join. That should insure the same encoding on both sides.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/collations?view=sql-server-ver15